# VBA SUM Formula with Variables

Tags: excel, vba, sum

Based on the image below I'm trying to dynamically put a SUM function in the yellow/orange for the range above it (red). The trick is that from period to period the Total Assets Row will change, so I'm needing to find the yellow/orange range, and then from there SUM above it. Keeping in mind that the screenshot I've show isn't the entire table, so I can just find the Last non-empty row in the sheet.

My logic so far is to find the "Total Assets" Row - 1 (as this will change everytime) and the "Adjustment" Column, then once I'm able to get the formula working for the first column, I'll just paste it across the range.

[image]

This is what I have so far, I'm able to select the range I've set for rng1, however when I try and turn it into a formula, I can't seem to get it to work. it either just prints =SUM(rng1) or I get an RunTime Error '1004' Application Defined or Object Defined Error.

```
    Sub test()

Dim Total_Assets As Long, Total_Assets_1 As Long, Adjust_Row As Long, Adjust_Row_2 As Long
Dim rng1 As Range, rngFound As Range
Dim Adjustment_Cell As Long, Adjust_Column As Long

''Finding 'Total Assets'''
    With Sheet15
    
        'Finding starting cell
        Set rngFound = .Cells.Find("Adjustments", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
        Adjust_Column = rngFound.Column
        Adjust_Row = rngFound.Row
        Adjust_Row_2 = Adjust_Row + 2
        Else
        MsgBox "You've changed the title of the report to not include the word 'Adjustments'. Please change this back.", vbCritical, "Error"
        End If
        
        'Finding "Total Assets" Row
        Set rngFound = .Cells.Find("Total Assets", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
        Total_Assets = rngFound.Row
        Total_Assets_1 = Total_Assets - 1
        Else
        MsgBox "Couldn't find a Total Assets Row in Sheet15", vbCritical, "Error"
        End If
        
        'Finding Range Area To Sum
        
Set rng1 = .Range(.Cells(Adjust_Row_2, Adjust_Column).Address(False, False), .Cells(Total_Assets_1, Adjust_Column).Address(False, False))

.Range("G17").Formula = "=SUM(&rng1&)"

       End With
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `"=SUM(" & rng1.Address & ")"`

Comment: Yep, that worked. I knew it was something simple.

Comment: Your issue is the understanding of how to concatenate string, variable shouldn't be enclosed with `"` like what you did, same for the operator `&`.